# How we restrict datagrid column drag drop

Tags: apache-flex

How we restrict datagrid column drag drop...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the demo with the source code
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/30/toggling-draggable-columns-in-a-flex-datagrid-control/